# problem current value not showing slider range html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Why is my value not showing when I slide HTML JS? I want the value of the slider to show in the h3 class number.

```js
function rangeSlider(value) {
  document.getElementsByClassName("agenumber").innerText = value;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="titreage">Select your age</h3>
<input type="range" min="6" max="60" step="1" value="50" class="slider" onmousemove="rangeSlider(this.value)" onchange="rangeSlider(this.value)">
<h3 class="agenumber"></h3>
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("agenumber")[0].innerText=value;` will do it

Comment: Or if you're updating only one element, use an id instead

Comment: it did actually worked i changed output to an id weirdly worked thanks a lot

Comment: It's not "weirdly" at all. getElement**s**byClassName finds multiple elements, you can't set an attribute to an array and expect that it magically applies to all of its contents.